# Fluid energy mills with powdered reactive metals

Tags: metallurgy

Can fluid energy mills manufacture spherical powdered metal of size ~5 micrometers in cases where the metal is quite reactive, like with lithium and aluminum, if the fluid used is a non reactive gas like argon or helium?

Comment: Relatively simple atomization with air made a large majority of zinc particles smaller than 400 mesh = smaller than 37 microns ( we had no need to measure as small as you ask).. I expect a more sophisticated system using argon could make a significant proportion of your 5 micron = 2500 mesh size. I don't know what a "fluid energy mill" is.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/fluid-energy

Comment: It's used to make particles in the 1-10 micrometer size.